# Spring JSON Data Not Returned Asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring WebMVC application that returns some JSON data on form submission for the purpose of populating a table

```
@RestController(value = "/search")
public class MyController{

@RequestMapping(produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<MyData> getMyData(@RequestParam("criteria") String criteria) { 
    List<MyData> mydata = dataRepository.findById(criteria);
    model.addAttribute("MyData", mydata);
    return mydata;
}
```

Here's my form:

```
<form method="get" id="searchForm" action="/myapp/search"> 
    <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="criteria"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="searchButton" value="Search"><br>
</form>
```

this is the json service I'm using in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

On the backend there's a Java config which sets up my Resource Handlers and Dispatcher servlet.

I'm trying to return this JSON data without returning an entirely new view or reloading the current page.

Essentially I want the data returned from

```
http://localhost:8090/myapp/search?critera=ABC
```

to be displayed on the same page as

```
http://localhost:8090/myapp
```

BONUS: How could this call be made with Alloy UI?

Comment: You should use ajax post to `http://localhost:8090/myapp/search?critera=ABC ` get response and update the DOM using javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a normal form submit which will reload the page. You have to do a ajax POST/ GET with XmlHttpRequest, grab the JSON your server is producing and update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

My particular issue was resolved by changing the "submit" input to a "button" input